# ProseMirror-Markdown tables not rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, markdown, prose-mirror

I have a need for table support using the ProseMirror-Markdown text editor in an Angular application which I am currently developing. I'm kind of stuck. I decided to go with prosemirror-markdown and its MarkdownSerializer due to existing functionality in the project which is now married to ProseMirror-Markdown.

```
// heading example

get schema() {
  return {
    toMarkdown: (state, node) => {
      state.write(`${state.repeat('#', node.attrs.level)} `)
      state.renderInline(node)
      state.closeBlock(node)
    },
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I encountered the same issues as the contributor for TipTap
[GitHub issue with prosemirror-markdown & GFM tables](https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/issues/66#issuecomment-457913275)

> No official table support One downside of using prosemirror-markdown
>       is that tables aren't support (and won't be). I could write that
>       part on my own but that means we have to drop some advanced
>       functionality for tables like multiple lines, nested tables, using
>       lists inside of tables etc. Maybe we should provide a Table node
>       with markdown support and a ExtendedTable without markdown support?
>
> After that I tried to implement a
>       parseMarkdown() function and this is way more complicated. There is
>       a MarkdownParser in prosemirror-markdown which is using markdown-it
>       under the hood. This is fine but means that we're limited by that
>       parser. I always thought there are markdown parsers out there with a
>       really simple api for extending but I guess I was wrong. :(

I am using MarkdownIt for parsing and serializing, below is the relevant `package.json` entries:

```
{...,
"markdown-it": "^9.1.0",
"markdown-it-table": "^2.0.4",
"prosemirror-keymap": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-markdown": "^1.3.1",
"prosemirror-model": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-state": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-transform": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-view": "^1.0.10",
"prosemirror-commands": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-example-setup": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-menu": "^1.0.0",
"prosemirror-schema-basic": "^1.0.0",
...}
```

I added some custom tokens to the parser and markdown-table, which is rendering correctly at a high level:

[image: Before clicking, markdown table rendering good :)]

However, even though I have cleared all unresolved token errors I get a partially rendered table in the editor view:

[image: In editor rendering... not so good]

These are the tokens which have been added to the parser on initialization:

```
+        table: {block: "table"},
+        thead: {block: "table_row"},
+        tr: {block: "table_row"},
+        td: {block: "table_cell"},
+        th: {block: "table_cell"},
+        tbody: {block: "tbody"},
```

These are the tables nodes which are being defined in the schema:

```
// Helper for creating a schema that supports tables.

function getCellAttrs(dom, extraAttrs) {
  let widthAttr = dom.getAttribute("data-colwidth")
  let widths = widthAttr && /^\d+(,\d+)*$/.test(widthAttr) ? widthAttr.split(",").map(s => Number(s)) : null
  let colspan = Number(dom.getAttribute("colspan") || 1)
  let result = {
    colspan,
    rowspan: Number(dom.getAttribute("rowspan") || 1),
    colwidth: widths && widths.length == colspan ? widths : null
  }
  for (let prop in extraAttrs) {
    let getter = extraAttrs[prop].getFromDOM
    let value = getter && getter(dom)
    if (value != null) result[prop] = value
  }
  return result
}

function setCellAttrs(node, extraAttrs) {
  let attrs = {}
  if (node.attrs.colspan != 1) attrs.colspan = node.attrs.colspan
  if (node.attrs.rowspan != 1) attrs.rowspan = node.attrs.rowspan
  if (node.attrs.colwidth)
    attrs["data-colwidth"] = node.attrs.colwidth.join(",")
  for (let prop in extraAttrs) {
    let setter = extraAttrs[prop].setDOMAttr
    if (setter) setter(node.attrs[prop], attrs)
  }
  return attrs
}
export function tableNodes(options) {
  let extraAttrs = options.cellAttributes || {}
  let cellAttrs = {
    colspan: {default: 1},
    rowspan: {default: 1},
    colwidth: {default: null}
  }
  for (let prop in extraAttrs)
    cellAttrs[prop] = {default: extraAttrs[prop].default}

  return {
    table: {
      content: "table_row+",
      tableRole: "table",
      isolating: true,
      group: options.tableGroup,
      parseDOM: [{tag: "table"}],
      toDOM() { return ["table", ["tbody", 0]] }
    },
    table_row: {
      content: "(table_cell | table_header)*",
      tableRole: "row",
      parseDOM: [{tag: "tr"}],
      toDOM() { return ["tr", 0] }
    },
    cell: {
      content: options.cellContent,
      attrs: cellAttrs,
      tableRole: "cell",
      isolating: true,
      parseDOM: [{tag: "td", getAttrs: dom => getCellAttrs(dom, extraAttrs)}],
      toDOM(node) { return ["td", setCellAttrs(node, extraAttrs), 0] }
    },
    table_header: {
      content: options.cellContent,
      attrs: cellAttrs,
      tableRole: "header_cell",
      isolating: true,
      parseDOM: [{tag: "th", getAttrs: dom => getCellAttrs(dom, extraAttrs)}],
      toDOM(node) { return ["th", setCellAttrs(node, extraAttrs), 0] }
    }
  }
}

export function tableNodeTypes(schema) {
  let result = schema.cached.tableNodeTypes
  if (!result) {
    result = schema.cached.tableNodeTypes = {}
    for (let name in schema.nodes) {
      let type = schema.nodes[name], role = type.spec.tableRole
      if (role) result[role] = type
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Anyone have experience with this or can come up with an alternative approach? Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!